# MySQL Pivot table using Join

Tags: mysql, join, pivot, pivot-table

```
Hey guys I am stuck at a problem in MySQL, can you please help me.
```

I have a form which gives ratings to certain parameters. Now what i want to do is i want to show a table in which for every LocationID all the parameter values should be shown in a single row.
This is my first table named interviewmaster where the records are stored

```
InterviewID     InterviewDate           IntervieweeID  SourceID   LocationID 
1           2013-06-10 16:11:09              1            1        3    
2           2013-06-10 16:12:19              2            2        2    
3           2013-06-10 16:13:05              3            5        5    
4           2013-06-10 16:13:46              4            4        6    
5           2013-06-10 16:14:35              5            2        1    
6           2013-06-10 16:15:26              6            3        7    
7           2013-06-10 16:16:05              7            5        8    
8           2013-06-10 16:16:51              8            1        4    
9           2013-06-10 16:22:31              9            5        3    
10          2013-06-11 08:51:20             10            1        1
```

My second table is interviewparameters

```
ParameterID   Parameter
1            The Welcome
2            Quality Of Service
3            Speed Of Service
4            Staff Attitude
5            Quality of food/beverage
6            Overall value for money
7            Ambience
8            Overall Experience
```

My third table is interviewratings

```
InterviewID parameterID Rating
1                  1    5
1                  2    4
1                  3    5
1                  4    4
1                  5    5
1                  6    4
1                  7    5
2                  1    5
2                  2    5
2                  3    5
2                  4    5
2                  5    5
2                  6    4
2                  7    5
3                  1    4
3                  2    3
3                  3    4
3                  4    3
3                  5    4
3                  6    3
3                  7    4
4                  1    2
4                  2    2
4                  3    2
4                  4    2
4                  5    2
4                  6    2
4                  7    2
```

Now the query that i am using is

```
select LocationID,
(CASE when ParameterID=1  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Welcome,
(CASE when ParameterID=2  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Service,
(CASE when ParameterID=3  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Speed,
(CASE when ParameterID=4  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Quality,
(CASE when ParameterID=5  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Overall,
(CASE when ParameterID=6  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Ambience,
(CASE when ParameterID=7  then avg(interviewratings.Rating) else null end) as Experience
from interviewratings join interviewmaster on
interviewratings.InterviewID=interviewmaster.InterviewID 
group by ParameterID, LocationID
```

This gives the result as

```
LocationID    welcome   source   speed   quality   overall   Ambiance   experience
1     2.8333                         
2     3.0000                        
3     3.4000                        
4     2.5000                        
5     2.3333                        
6     2.8000                        
7     2.8182                        
8     4.0000                        
1             3.0000                    
2             2.5714                    
3             3.2000                    
4             3.3333                    
5             2.6667                    
6             2.8000                    
7             2.3636                    
8             4.3333                    
1                     3.0000                
2                     2.5714                
3                     3.4000                
4                     2.8333                
5                     3.8889                
6                     2.8000                
7                     2.7273                
8                     3.3333                
1                              3.0000           
2                              4.2857           
3                              3.2000           
4                              3.5000           
5                              2.7778           
6                              2.8000           
7                              3.0000           
8                              3.0000           
1                                        3.0000     
2                                        2.8571     
3                                        3.4000     
4                                        2.8333     
5                                        3.6667     
6                                        2.8000     
7                                        3.1818     
8                                        2.6667     
1                                                 3.0000    
2                                                 2.4286    
3                                                 3.2000    
4                                                 2.8333    
5                                                 2.6667    
6                                                 3.6000    
7                                                 3.0909    
8                                                 3.0000    
1                                                        3.0000
2                                                        2.8571
3                                                        3.8000
4                                                        2.5000
5                                                        2.6667
6                                                        2.8000
7                                                        3.0909
8                                                        3.3333
```

Location table is

```
LocationID  Location
1      Seasonal Tastes
2      Daily Treats
3      Eest
4      Prego
5      Mix
6      Splash
7      Xiao chi
8      The Living Room
```

I want my data to be like this

```
Location  Welcome  Service  Speed   Quality Overall Ambience  Experience
 seasonal     2.8333   3.0000   3.0000  3.0000  3.0000  3.0000    3.0000            
 Daily treats 3.0000   2.5714   2.5714  4.2857  2.8571  2.4286    2.8571            
 Eest         3.4000   3.2000   3.4000  3.2000  3.4000  3.2000    3.8000           
 Prego        2.5000   3.3333   2.8333  3.5000  2.8333  2.8333    2.5000                        
 Mix          2.3333   2.6667   3.8889  2.7778  3.6667  2.6667    2.6667            
 Splash       2.8000   2.8000   2.8000  2.8000  2.8000  3.6000    2.8000                  
 Xiao chi     2.8182   2.3636   2.7273  3.0000  3.1818  3.0909    3.0909               
 The Living   4.0000   4.3333   3.3333  3.0000  2.6667  3.0000    3.3333
```

and all the results in all the columns within these 8 rows.. can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: sorry about before, try the new query pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  l.Location,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=1  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=1  then 1 else 0 end) as Welcome,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=2  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=2  then 1 else 0 end) as Service,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=3  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=3  then 1 else 0 end) as Speed,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=4  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=4  then 1 else 0 end) as Quality,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=5  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=5  then 1 else 0 end) as Overall,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=6  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=6  then 1 else 0 end) as Ambience,
  sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=7  then r.Rating else 0 end)/sum(CASE when r.ParameterID=7  then 1 else 0 end) as Experience
from 
  interviewratings r
join interviewmaster m
  on m.InterviewID = r.InterviewID 
join Location l
  on l.LocationID = m.LocationID 
group by  
  m.LocationID
```

Comment: glad i could help :) don't forget to accept the answer so that other users see the solution

Comment: Hey man sorry to trouble you.. I found out that i need to show data like i have edited. In place of locationID i need to get location names from another table.. can you help me with it..

Comment: Hey man it has an error . "The welcome" is shown in all the 8 rows.

Comment: my bad sorry... instead of location table i used parameter table... ill update the query

Comment: Yes it works man.. thanks a lot. Sorry to ask easy questions but am new at this. I was thinking if I want to get the maximum and minimum value of the column. I am using a data grid and this query shows the table properly. Now I want to highlight the maximum rating as green and minimum rating as red of a particular column so that I know which destination is best in which department. Can you tell me is that possible ?

Comment: yes it possible ... but i think its easier for you to do this from code side

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT l.Location,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=1 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Welcome,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=2 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Service,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=3 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Speed,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=4 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Quality,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=5 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Overall,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=6 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Ambience,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.ParameterID=7 THEN r.Rating ELSE NULL END) Experience
  FROM interviewmaster i JOIN Location l 
    ON i.LocationID = l.LocationID JOIN interviewratings r
    ON i.InterviewID = r.InterviewID
 GROUP BY i.LocationID, l.Location
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a21ea/3)** demo

Comment: +1 this was my original idea but this , i think, will mess up the avg

Comment: Peterm your query works.. thanks for another approach.. cheers !!